# Django language selection does not work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, python, django, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to set up a language selector using the Framework Django.

I used this code:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value=""/>

    <select class="select-style" name="language" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="width:100px">
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% if lang.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

It works well with Chrome and Safari but not Firefox.

The 1st language (English) is not displayed in the drop-down menu.

/ setting.py /

```
LANGUAGES = (
   ('en', gettext('English')),
   ('fr', gettext('French')),
   ('nl', gettext('Dutch')),
   ('it', gettext('Italian')),
   ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
   ('th', gettext('Thai')),
)
```

Thanks

EDIT

I've finally fixed my problem adding a selected=selected field option which is displayed only in Chrome and Safari but at least all languages are displayed in FF.

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value=""/>

    <select class="select-style" name="language" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="width:100px;font-size:12px;">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select your language</option>
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% if lang.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{lang.1|title}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it already showing the English site?

Comment: Depending on the country where you visit the site. If I'm in UK, the first time the site will be in English. But if I change to another language, I couln't select the English anymore. Also, in settings.py, if I put French in the first position, I couldn't select French anymore.